# How to embed a video in an HTML document from my computer?

Tags: html, html5-video

I am trying to attach a video from my MacBook to a webpage in HTML 5 in brackets code editor, but the video is not playing in the browser(chrome), while the box and controls for the video is visible.The video is stored in one of my folders named videos on my hard-drive.

Tried to use mpeg extension in place of mp4, and I tried to use a different path in the src attribute. Also tried to use a second source tag which is commented below in the code.

```
<body>
<video controls>
<source src="video1.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
<!--<source src="video1.ogg" type="video/ogg">-->
</video>
</body>
```

Everything is alright including box, controls, but only the video is not playing.

Comment: yes please check that, i forgot to add it

Comment: Are the video and the html file in the same folder?

Comment: no, they are not

Comment: if they are in diferent folders, and your code is like above - you have invalid path. 
otherwise can you play video in browser when you enter it directly (via full url?) because it looks like player is created properly, but browser cannot play file (invalid codec etc..)

have you checked browser console (F12) for any messages/warnings?

Comment: yeah you are right but now i got that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path you wrote in the `src` attribute is relative to the location of the html file, you need to make sure that either the video is in the same folder or that the path points to the folder in which the video is stored.

Example:

If the video is stored in the `videos` folder that is in the same folder as your html file:

```
src="videos/video1.mp4"
```

You can also provide src for multiple formats --

```
<video controls> 
    <source src="videos/video1.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="videos/video1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: No problem :) please mark the answer to indicate that your problem is solved